# How can I split html value and normal string into different array in php?

Tags: php, regex

Say I have string such as below:

```
"b<a=2<sup>2</sup>"
```

Actually its a formula. I need to display this formula on webpage but after b string is hiding because its considered as broken anchor tag. I tried with htmlspecialchars method  but it returns complete string as plain text. I am trying with some regex but I can get only text between some tags.

Comment: Use [`htmlentities("b<a=2<sup>2</sup>")`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) ( or maybe `htmlentities("b<a=2")."<sup>2</sup>"` )to display the string in a webpage.

Comment: @chris85 Yes, I had already corrected :)

Comment: @ fusion3k, am getting "b < a = 2<sup>2</sup>"  as a string from some api. So how can i decide which part of the string to be passed htmlentities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### UPDATE:

This seems to work with this formula:

```
"(c<a) = (b<a) = 2<sup>2</sup>"
```

And even with this formula:

```
"b<a=2<sup>2</sup>"
```

#### HERE'S THE MAGIC:

```
<?php

$_string = "b<a=2<sup>2</sup>";
$string = "(c<a) = (b<a) = 2<sup>2</sup>";

$open_sup = strpos($string,"<sup>");
$close_sup = strpos($string,"</sup>");

$chars_array = str_split($string);

foreach($chars_array as $index => $char)
{
    if($index != $open_sup && $index != $close_sup)
    {
        if($char == "<")
        {
            echo "&lt;";
        }
        else{
            echo $char;
        }
    }
    else{
        echo $char;
    }
}
```

#### OLD SOLUTION (DOESN'T WORK)

Maybe this can help:

I've tried to backslash chars, but it doesn't work as expected. 
Then i've tried this one:

```
<?php

$string = "b&lta=2<sup>2</sup>";

echo $string;
?>
```

Using &lt html entity it seems to work if i understood your problem... 
Let me know

Comment: am getting "b < a = 2<sup>2</sup>" as a string from some api. I need some logic to replace < tag to &lta

Comment: But do you need to replace even the <sup angle bracket  with &lt or just the first one?

Comment: Considering above example, just the first one. But formula may like (c<a) = (b<a) = 2<sup>2</sup>, so replacing first <a of string wont help it seems

Comment: Ok so you need an algorithm that knows which to transform into &lt and which to leave as <... 
Let me think something...

Comment: Can you find more pairs of <sup>2</sup> or there is just one in any formula?

Comment: `&lt` is an invalid entity, whatever you are testing this in is autocorrecting. That will break in other browsers, entities end with a semicolon.

Comment: @chris85 do you mean that i have to code it like this?  echo "&lt;"; ?

Comment: @Caius, yes that would be it, because the entity is `&lt;`.

Comment: @chris85 Good to know. I've updated the code. Thanks

Comment: @Caius Awesome... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can give spaces such as :

```
b < a = 2<sup>2</sup>
```

It does not disappear the tag and looks much more understanding....

Answer (score 0):

You could try this regex approach, which should skip elements.

```
$regex = '/<(.*?)\h*.*>.+<\/\1>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(<|>)/';
$string = 'b<a=2<sup>2</sup>';
$string = preg_replace_callback($regex, function($match) {
    return htmlentities($match[2]);
}, $string);
echo $string;
```

Output:

```
b&lt;a=2<sup>2</sup>
```

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/507605
Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/kD0iM0/1